# Change row Row color if the cell in Raw has unique value

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a code to change the row colour if the cell in the row have some special value. But now I have a requirement to change the row colour if the last two letters of the cell value is 'AP'. For example if any cell in column A has a value Orange11AP then the row colour should change to red. I am kind of stuck with the cell value as it is a mixed of letter and digits. Can someone kindly help me on here ?

Comment: Please share what do you already have and also some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `cell` as the `Range` variable holding the current cell in a loop, you may want to use:

```
If Right(cell,2) = "AP" Then cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
```

Comment: Sorry Guys, I dont fully get you. My current code will change the font colour of Cell D if there is any plank value in cell P. But now my requirement changed to whenever there is a "AP" at the end of the value of cell P then entire row ( from A to Q) should change to red. Following is my current code

Comment: count2 = Range("F:F").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row <br/>
      
For n = 2 To count2 <br/>
       
If Range("P" & n).Value = vbNullString Then <br/>
Range("D" & n).Font.Bold = True <br/>
Range("D" & n).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255) <br/>

Answer (score 0):

Make it case insensitive just to be on the safe side.

If LCase(Right(Activecell.Value,2)) = LCase("AP") Then Activecell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed